# Show greeting each time opening Terminal Linux

Tags: linux, macos

I want the Terminal to show `Hello, alex!` each time I open the Terminal on my Linux computer or my Mac.

Comment: I found similar question and answers on other forums [What are the different ways that a message can be displayed to a bash shell after a user logs in?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32435/366565), and there you should find the answer.

Comment: This one too https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171938/how-to-display-welcome-message-in-unix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you using bash:

```
echo echo Hi, $(id -un)! >> ~/.bashrc
```

using Zsh

```
echo echo Hi, $(id -un)! >> ~/.zshrc
```

This command adds a new line to .bashrc or .zshrc file `echo Hi, $(current_user)`. You can open the file and manually add it.

Comment: This approach is fine but will only work for a single user unless the amendments are made to every users home bashrc/zshrc file or the amendment is made to /etc/profile

Answer (score 1):

This is typically achieved by editing /etc/motd (message of the day)

The following article demonstrates what can be acheived:

https://www.networkworld.com/article/3219736/how-to-use-the-motd-file-to-get-linux-users-to-pay-attention.html

In your particular scenario you could add a line:

```
echo "Hello $(whoami)"\!
```

or

```
echo "Hello $(id -un)"\!
```

to /etc/motd to achieve what you want.

Comment: Yeah, thanks so much for the info. But I found somewhere that `whoami` is deprecated.

Comment: You can you id then but /etc/motd is designed for logon messaging.

Comment: If you want the messaging to be restricted to one users the approved approach will work. If you want it across multiple users, it won't